# android read file from assets in real time

Tags: android, assets, android-file

I want to read last line of a text file from assets and get a new data I just add, so I try using handler but still got the same result.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String lastLine = "";
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("kinect_gesture.txt")));
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                lastLine = sCurrentLine;
            }

            TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gesture);
            txt.setText(lastLine);
        }catch( java.io.FileNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch( java.io.IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }
};
```

Is there a way to get new data from text file while running app?

Comment: You can't change file inside assets folder but what you can do is copy these file somewhere else (internal or external) and change those files.

Comment: @resw67 Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get new data from text file while running app?

No, because that is not a text file. That is an asset. An asset is read-only at runtime. It does not change while the app is running. To change the asset, you rebuild and redeploy your app.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep text file somewhere else and if not working, I'll try using clound instead. :)